Determine the functions $f:\Bbb N^* \to \Bbb N^*$ such that $\frac3{f(1)+f(2)+\dots+f(n)}=\frac4{f(n)}-\frac4{f(n+1)}$ for any $n \in\Bbb N^*$
The problem
Determine the functions $f:\Bbb N^* \to\Bbb N^*$ with the property that: $\dfrac{3}{f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)} = \dfrac{4}{f(n)}- \dfrac{4}{f(n+1)}$ for any $n \in\Bbb N^*$
My idea
The first thing that came in my mind is that formula that says that $\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}=\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}$
And maybe we can take all these functions in a member and process them. I tried doing it but to be honest in got to nothing useful.

Is $\mathbb{N}^* = {1,2,3,\dots} $?

@ScottishQuestions You would hope so, as starting with $\frac30$ is not a good idea (looking at the initial denominator as an empty sum)

As suggested in response to your previous question: “List out like the first 20 values, and make some conjectures.”

@ScottishQuestions Yeah, that s what it means

@MartinR What values?

$f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5)$

Put $n=1$ in the recurrence gives $f(2)=4f(1)$. Putting $n=2$ and solving gives $f(3)=10f(1)$. Similarly, $n=3$ gives $f(4)=20f(1)$, Hence we might conjecture that $f(n)=T_nf(1)$, where $T_n=n(n+1)(n+2)/6$ is the $n$-th tetrahedral number, and the result follows from a simple induction proof.
Edit: For the induction part: Suppose the statement is true for $n=1,\cdots, k$, then for $n=k+1:$
$$\frac{3}{\sum_{i=1}^kf(i)}=\frac{4}{f(k)}-\frac{4}{f(k+1)},$$
or
$$\frac{4}{f(k+1)}=\frac{4}{T_kf(1)}-\frac{3}{\sum_{i=1}^kT_if(1)},$$
by the induction hypothesis and the formulae $\sum_{i=1}^ni=n(n+1)/2, \sum_{i=1}^ni^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6, \sum_{i=1}^ni^3=n^2(n+1)^2/4$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^kT_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i(i+1)(i+2)}{6}=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{24}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{4}{f(k+1)}=\frac{1}{f(1)}\left(\frac{4}{T_k}-\frac{3}{\sum_{i=1}^kT_i}\right)=\frac{1}{f(1)}\left(\frac{24}{k(k+1)(k+2)}-\frac{72}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}\right),$$
Simplifying gives
$$\frac{4}{f(k+1)}=\frac{24}{f(1)(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$$
or $f(k+1)=T_{k+1}f(1)$ and we are done.

Nice solution! Just a small typo, it should be $n=1$, $n=2$ and $n=3$.

You are right, updated, thanks!

@Ishigami First of all i cant prove the induction. Also there is no way of calculating $f(1)$? Thanks for your idea!

@PamMunozRyan the easiest way to go about is to use the recurrence $T_n=T_{n-1}+n$. Alternatively, just brute force you way out with $\sum_i i(i+1)(i+2)/6$ using the formula for $\sum_i i^3, \sum_i i^2, \sum_i i$. For $f(1)$, it could be any non-zero natural number so there are infinitely many solutions.

@Ishigami Sorry, but still im stuck. can you please write it down? Im giving you a bounty is I ask too much

@PamMunozRyan See the edit:)

@Ishigami Thank you so much! May i ask why we took the case $n=k+1$, but still had $...-\frac{4}{f(k+1)}$? Also how did you use the hypothesis and those formulas to get to that? Thanks again and I'm sorry if I'm annoying
